# UIView deforms when it is animated to another position

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

Im having a really stupid problem with a UIView. I create the UIView programatically and then make it a circle by making the corner radius half the height of the view looks like this:

[image: (UIView)]

But when I try to animate the circle to a different location it becomes all deformed like this:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to animate the view just a simple UIView.animateWithDuration:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
                    self.secondDot.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width - self.secondDot.frame.size.width, y: 0)
                    self.secondDot.frame.size = self.secondDot.frame.size
                    }, completion: nil)
```

I should also add that the circle doesn't always become deformed but more often than not it does. Please help any suggestions would be much appreciated.

> EDIT: I should mention that the circle is in motion already before the
>   UIView.animationWithDuration occurs I don't know if that could be a
>   problem

Comment: In this case, it might be helpful to know where you are trying to call UIView.animateWithDuration.  This one individual call looks OK, and doesn't look like enough context to explain the behavior you're seeing.   What is the type of `secondDot` for example?  Is it a UIView?

Comment: self.secondDot is a type UIView

Comment: If the view is already being animated through a different animation context, then you should be able to get away with simply changing the position of the view, you shouldn't have to open another animation context.  What happens if you just change the origin of the view without the call to `UIView.animateWithDuration`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of this line?

```
self.secondDot.frame.size = self.secondDot.frame.size
```

You either

1. want to resize the circle uniformly while moving
2. or not.

If case 1) the the newSize.width != newSize.height...but thats a problem because your circle is not a "square" anymore behind the scenes.
If case 2) just remove the lines.

Comment: yes that line was my attempt to keep it from deforming but it didn't work and I just removed it again to make sure, still looks like the image above (deformed) I should mention that the circle is in motion already before the UIView.animationWithDuration occurs I don't know if that could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I had exactely the same situation.

After some research, I've found comment in header file for `setFrame` method

> // animatable. do not use frame if view is transformed since it will
>   not correctly reflect the actual location of the view. use bounds +
>   center instead.

I have decided to use `setCenter` instead of `setFrame` which solved the distortion issue.